# How to use < > in Visual Studio comments?

Tags: visual-studio, xml-comments

Below comment is just a piece of xml comment in VS but my problem is characters like `< >` that break the xml structure. How can I use them in an xml comment?

```
/// <param name="index">square index on board which 1<=index<=64</param>
```

Comment: What about `&lt` and `&gt`, would they work?

Comment: Let me guess, chess/draughts board? :p

Comment: @Psytronic It is chess Engine which i haven't publish yet on codeplex :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/// <param name="index">square index on board which 1&lt;=index&lt;=64</param>
```

OR

```
/// <param name="index">square index on board which 1〈=index〈=64</param>
```

The latter option is unicode: 〈 〉

Comment: Why use unicode if less than and greater than are part of the xml spec? Not a criticism, just a wonder.

Comment: Depending on fonts, it might be immediately readable both in the comment and the xml extract.

Answer (score 5):

I would reword it to be more a sentence and less an equation:

```
/// <param name="index">square index on board, between 1 and 64</param>
```

Comment: Between means 1 and 64 included ?

Comment: If you are concerned that your audience for the comment might think a chessboard could be 2 <= index <= 63, you could say "between 1 and 64 inclusive." I think the importance of the comment is really to distinguish "0-63" from "1-64". But word it as you feel you need to for those who will read it.

Answer (score 4):

Try encoding them? using &lt; and &gt;

Comment: I think that will look awful when you're reading the code. I also think more people will read the code than will read the doc you generate from it.